# GWT Hide grouped data in DataGrid

Tags: java, gwt

We're using GWT. I have a DataGrid with many repeated values in the column on the left. I would like to hide these. For example:

I have:

```
Town        | Address             | Color
------------------------------------------
Springfield | Springfield Heights | Blue
Springfield | Bum town            | Red
Springfield | Little Italy        | Blue
Shelbyville | Manhattan Square    | Green
Shelbyville | Chinatown           | Red
```

I would like to have:

```
Town        | Address             | Color
------------------------------------------
Springfield | Springfield Heights | Blue
            | Bum town            | Red
            | Little Italy        | Blue
Shelbyville | Manhattan Square    | Green
            | Chinatown           | Red
```

I tried a few things, but they don't work well with sortable columns. Is there a standard way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override `getCellStyleNames` for your cell used for Town column. This method gives you Context, which you can use to see where this cell is in the column (`context.getIndex()`). Using this information, you can compare value in this cell with value in the cell above it (if any). If it is the same, return a style to hide value in this cell.

Note that it won't work if you simply return empty value when overriding `getValue` for you cell, because it will make the next cell show its value even if it is the same. You can, of course, work around this by looking up until you find a non-empty cell, but overriding `getCellStyleNames` and simply hiding repeating values looks like a simpler solution.

Because this is a method in your cell, it should behave well with updates, sorting columns, etc.

Comment: Thanks, this put me on the right track. The getCellStyleNames was in the column, not in the cell, but I have something working now.